# Check the valid Indices among 8 nearest Neighbors

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have divied an Image into number of subimages. Now I want to compare the average intensity of each subimage with its 8 neighbors. But in some points there would be less than 8 neighbors. For example for the first block(i=1,J=1), the upperleft block(i-1,j-1) does not exist. How can I check this and skip to the next valid one?

```
file='myimg.bmp';
I=imread(file);

blockSizeR = 128; % Rows in block.
blockSizeC = 128; % Columns in block.

wholeBlockRows = floor(rows / blockSizeR);
blockVectorR = [blockSizeR * ones(1, wholeBlockRows), rem(rows, blockSizeR)];

wholeBlockCols = floor(columns / blockSizeC);
blockVectorC = [blockSizeC * ones(1, wholeBlockCols), rem(columns, blockSizeC)];

ca = mat2cell(I, blockVectorR, blockVectorC);

%get the mean value of each cell
meanValues = cellfun(@(x) mean(x(:)),ca);


for j=1:size(ca(2))
    for i=1:size(ca(1))
        currentSlice = ca(i,j);
        MeanOfCurrentSlice =  cellfun(@(x) mean(x(:)),currentSlice);

        %here I want to minus the 8 neighbors average grayscale intensity from the currentSlice average grayscale inensity and take the absolute sum 

    end

end
```

Comment: Provide [**a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Sardar_Usama, 

Which point you did not understand?

Comment: You're getting an *annoying error*, okay so you expect people to guess your code and find problem in it?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama the error is `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.` because Johar try to access an element of his structure with a negativ index.

Comment: @obchardon
Yes, thats my problem. How can I check this in matlab and skip to the valid one.

Comment: @Sardar_Usama the error was not my question. Removed it.

Comment: Also you should explain what you mean by `compare`.

Comment: @obchardon
did it.

Comment: "%here I want to minus the 8 neighbors average grayscale intensity from the currentSlice average grayscale inensity and take the absolute sum" - sounds like a 2-dimensional convolution. There's a built-in function for that, you know. This is why it's important to tell us what you're actually doing so you don't waste time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @beaker  in convolution you apply a mask and then slide, my problem is slightly different you see. I already know mean intensity of all the blocks. now want to compare each block with its  valid neighbors.

Comment: Put the mean from each block into a matrix, in order. Convolution.

Comment: @beaker

Upadted the question. Can you have a look.

Comment: @beaker
I am cordially sorry. I have no intention to disrespect the people who are trying to help me.  I hope you would not misunderstand me.

Comment: @Nektar No problem, thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that give you the index of the nearest neighbor for each element:

```
%creation of the index matrix (here a 3x3 matrix)
M = reshape([1:9],3,3);

%subdivide the matrix into 3x3 array
IND = nlfilter(M,[3 3],@(x){x(:)});

%elimination of the value where IND == 0 or IND == index value of the element
for ii = 1:size(M,1)
    for jj = 1:size(M,2)
        IND{ii,jj}(IND{ii,jj}==0|IND{ii,jj}==sub2ind(size(M),ii,jj)) = [];
    end
end
```

PS: `nlfilter`is part of the image processing toolbox, but it's easy to create your own similar function.

**STEP 1:**

```
M =

   1   4   7
   2   5   8
   3   6   9
```

**STEP 2:**

```
IND = 
{
  [1,1] = 
     0   0   0   0   1   2   0   4   5
  [2,1] =
     0   0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
  [3,1] =
     0   0   0   2   3   0   5   6   0
  [1,2] =
     0   1   2   0   4   5   0   7   8
  [2,2] =
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
  [3,2] =
     2   3   0   5   6   0   8   9   0
  [1,3] =
     0   4   5   0   7   8   0   0   0
  [2,3] =
     4   5   6   7   8   9   0   0   0
  [3,3] =
     5   6   0   8   9   0   0   0   0
}
```

**STEP 3:**

```
IND =
{
  [1,1] = %neighbors of the value M[1,1] 
     2   4   5
  [2,1] =
     1   3   4   5   6
  [3,1] =
     2   5   6
  [1,2] =
     1   2   5   7   8
  [2,2] =
     1   2   3   4   6   7   8   9
  [3,2] =
     2   3   5   8   9
  [1,3] =
     4   5   8
  [2,3] =
     4   5   6   7   9
  [3,3] =
     5   6   8
}
```

Comment: getting an error in the 7th line
|
Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error, this code work on my computer.

Comment: I need to understand the 7th line where you eliminate or skip the IND = 0.
Can you explain a litle bit how this line avoiding the invalid indexes? and how you are getting the valid indexes for further opertion to be done?

Comment: I added the intermediate results and I change the example, now I use a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: ok, got it. Thanks man :) l also updated my question fearing that people might not understand my point.

Comment: Edited the question.